# Java Collection::toArray with subclasses

Tags: java, generics, collections, toarray, subtyping

Is there a way to use the `Collection::toArray(T[])` method when you only know the subtype of the collection?

Take this example:

```
void initList(Collection<? extends AorB> data) {
    JList<? extends AorB> aorb_jlist = new JList<>();
    aorb_jlist.setListData(data.toArray(new T<? extends AorB>[data.size()]));
}

abstract class AorB {}
class A extends AorB {}
class B extends AorB {}
```

(I just put `T` there for illustration, I know that wouldn't work)

All I know about the `Collection` is that it is a subclass of `AorB`, but it could be either. The `JList` accepts `<? extends AorB>` as its type, but the `setListData` method needs an array, and `Collection::toArray` needs input.

Am I barking up the wrong tree with `toArray`? Is there an easy, efficient way to convert this Collection to array without manually iterating over it?

**Edit to answer @PaulBoddington:**

You can't change `<? extends AorB>` to `<AorB>` because then the method won't receive a Collection of subtypes:

Example:

```
void initList(Collection<AorB> data) {
    JList<AorB> aorb_jlist = new JList<>();
    aorb_jlist.setListData(data.toArray(new AorB[data.size()]));
}

abstract class AorB {}
class A extends AorB {}
class B extends AorB {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<A> a_list = new LinkedList<>();
    initList(a_list);
}
```

throws an error:

```
incompatible types: LinkedList<A> cannot be converted to Collection<AorB>
```

Comment: Can't you just use a `JList<AorB>` and an `AorB[]`?

Comment: @PaulBoddington, whether JList uses `<AorB>` or `<? extends AorB>`, you still have to convert the `Collection` to an array. How do you convert a `Collection<? extends AorB>` to an array?

Comment: `collection.toArray(new AorB[collection.size()]);`

Comment: Oh you mean change the `Collection` type to `<AorB>`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington, no because if I then try to feed the method with a Collection of (real) subclassed values, it throws an error. `LinkedList<A> cannot be cast to Collection<AorB>`

Comment: @PaulBoddington, I edited the question with an example implementation of your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the collection as `Collection<? extends AorB>`, but make the JList a `JList<AorB>`:

```
void initList(Collection<? extends AorB> data) {
    JList<AorB> aorb_jlist = new JList<>();
    aorb_jlist.setListData(data.toArray(new AorB[data.size()]));
}
```

Comment: Good point, of course it generates warning: `Suspicious Collection.toArray() call. Collection item type ? extends AorB is not assignable to array component type AorB`. I can see how this would work, but it makes me reevaluate my understanding of what it means to use bounded wildcards on `JList`s.